# Is there a name for this data structure that is kind of "opposite" of a tree?

Tags: data-structures, tree

We all know what a tree is: on the first level of a tree we have a root, and from the root come branches that are trees as well. But how do I name the "opposite" structure: on the i-th level we have a set of "leaf" nodes, and those nodes form groups of 1+ nodes, and a group points to a "trunk" node on i+1th level. If you want a visual example, imagine raindrops flowing down a window and combining as they collide.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of tree data structures are actually constructed from leaf to root, and can be stored to allow for going one or both directions.

I don't think it really has a special name as it's more a convention than a requirement for trees typically to go from root to leaf rather than the other way or both ways. Also there are a number of tree data structures that allow for going both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Every tree is a DAG, a directed acyclic graph, and so is the data-structure that you describe. What you describe is also a [multitree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitree), a subset of DAGs. Possibly there is a more precise real subset of multitrees that describes your graph, but I am not aware of it. Hope this helps.